# Jupyter nbextensions doesn´t appear - 404 GET /static/components/marked/lib/marked.js

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, anaconda3, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

#### Steps done

After introduce the next commands.

`conda create -n dsenv python=3.10`

`conda activate dsenv`

`pip install jupyter`

`pip install jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.1`

`jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`

Everything went well.

But when i enter the next command `jupyter notebook`, appears jupyter notebook webpage http://localhost:8888/tree but the tab of nbextensions doesn´t appears.

[Jupyter Notebook WebPage Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnHJG.png)

The console give a error message: `404 GET /static/components/marked/lib/marked.js?v=20230223000607 (::1) 15.950000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree`

#### Environment specifications

My Operative System (OS): `Windows 10`

Shell used: Anaconda Prompt

My list of libraries installed are:

```
anyio                     3.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi               21.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
arrow                     1.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     22.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
beautifulsoup4            4.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    6.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           haa95532_0
certifi                   2022.12.7       py310haa95532_0
cffi                      1.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.6.6                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
fastjsonschema            2.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
fqdn                      1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
ipykernel                 6.21.2                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                8.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
isoduration               20.11.0                  pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonpointer               2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            8.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-console           6.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-contrib-core      0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions 0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-events            0.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-highlight-selected-word 0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-latex-envs        1.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-terminals  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
libffi                    3.4.2                hd77b12b_6
lxml                      4.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   2.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclassic                 0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 7.2.9                    pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.7.3                    pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1t               h2bbff1b_0
packaging                 23.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pickleshare               0.7.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.3.1          py310haa95532_0
platformdirs              3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prometheus-client         0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt-toolkit            3.0.37                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pure-eval                 0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21                     pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.19.3                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.9               h966fe2a_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
python-json-logger        2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   305                      pypi_0    pypi
pywinpty                  2.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     25.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qtconsole                 5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qtpy                      2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                65.6.3          py310haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.40.1               h2bbff1b_0
stack-data                0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tinycss2                  1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
tornado                   6.2                      pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2022g                h04d1e81_0
uri-template              1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
webcolors                 1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websocket-client          1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.38.4          py310haa95532_0
widgetsnbextension        4.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2             py310haa95532_2
xz                        5.2.10               h8cc25b3_1
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
```

Comment: Getting the same error. Has this been resolved?

Comment: Yep, I have written as an answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related with the new updates of `notebook`, it gives problems with ".js" files that get lost with the update.

The solution is to get back to previous version:

In my case it was get back to 6.1.5 but in another cases it would be get to another previous version

`pip install notebook==6.1.5`

The users that has more compability problems they would use next one:

`pip install notebook==5.7.10`

**It is better to use `pip install` than `conda` command, because conda produce compability problems in many cases with dependences packages**

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in the network console of the browser.

Here is how I worked this around:

1. In the anaconda310 directory, type `find . -name render.js`, then I found two render.js
   ./share/jupyter/nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/render/render.js
   ./lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/static/nbextensions_configurator/render/render.js
2. I vim the ./share/jupyter/nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/render/render.js and found that it used marked.js. I searched marked.js by `find . -name marked.js`, and found that it is in ./lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclassic/static/components/marked/lib/marked.js
3. It Looks like there are duplicate nbextensions installed in anaconda310, and the copy in ./share has higher priority. I confirmed this by `find . -name nbextensions`
4. Then I removed ./share/jupyter/nbextensions, and everything was sorted. (another option is to install nbclassic to ./share)

Comment: Great inspections of the files and packages :)! Thx to add information about the problem. For me the answer above worked well but anyway i´ll check your instructions.